# raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

При вызове json.loads() получаю ошибку

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

структура json файла:

```
{
    "db": [
        {
          "message_id": 1156
        },
        {
          "message_id": 1155
        },
        {
          "message_id": 1154
        }
    ]
}
```

функция:

```
def cout():
    for i in json.loads("hist.json"):
        print(i)

cout()
```

Какие могут быть решения? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/17_serialization/2_json.html):

loads - принимает json в виде строки. Код ругается, что `"hist.json"` - это не json и ему не понять, что это.

load - загружает из файлового объекта. В конкретном случае надо так:

```
import json

def cout():
    with open('hist.json', 'r') as hist:
        for i in json.load(hist):
            print(i)

cout()
```

А еще JSON-формат ругается на лишние запятые. и поэтому в файле надо удалить последнюю запятую у последнего элемента списка.

PS: А `loads` используется так:

```
import json

def cout():
    for i in json.loads("""
    {
        "db": [
            {
            "message_id": 1156
            },
            {
            "message_id": 1155
            },
            {
            "message_id": 1154
            }
        ]
    }
    """):
        print(i)

cout()
```

Comment: спасибо огромное! Про запятую знаю, у меня ее в жсоне и нет, это вырванный кусок из огромного json.